# How to decrypt 3DES in ECB mode (using a wordlist)?

Tags: python, des, 3d-secure

I have some encrypted texts (encrypted with 3DES in ECB mode without salt).

**My question: How can I decrypt them using a wordlist? (or without one?)**

Example:

Encrypted text:

```
Xfi+h4Ir6l7zXCP+N4EPvQ==
```

The wordlist for this:

```
foo
bar
marketing
```

The original text was before encrypting was: "marketing" (just to make the example full).

I tried with the commented python script:

```
$ cat 3des.py 
 #!/usr/local/bin/python

from pyDes import *

data = "marketing"
k = des("DESCRYPT", CBC, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
d = k.encrypt(data)
print "Encrypted: %r" % d
print "Decrypted: %r" % k.decrypt(d)
assert k.decrypt(d, padmode=PAD_PKCS5) == data
```

testing it:

```
$ python 3des.py 
Encrypted: '\xabd\xfc\x98x\x86\x8d\xb5A\xba\x8e\x12,\x1f\x83\xb5'
Decrypted: 'marketing'
$
```

A little help please?

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard. Just use Python ( thanks @DallasMoore ) to iterate through a text file of potential keys. Use `for x in range(y)` in conjunction with `readlines`, don't add everything to a list.

Comment: I tried, no luck yet, "imma no programmer ;) "

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: read my question again please: "How can I decrypt them using a wordlist? (or without one)"

Comment: hmm maybe the problem is you use DES not 3DES and CBC-mode instead of ECB

Comment: If this is new code, please don't use Triple DES. AES, Triple DES's replacement, is a better choice and has hardware support on modern Intel CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use pyDES, you'll first have to configure your the script to use 3DES...  Here's the provided pyDES example, modified to use 3DES:

```
from pyDes import *

data = "marketing"
k = triple_des("DESCRYPTDESCRYPT", ECB, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
d = k.encrypt(data)
print "Encrypted: %r" % d
print "Decrypted: %r" % k.decrypt(d)
assert k.decrypt(d, padmode=PAD_PKCS5) == data
```

To break it down...

The following line contains the class initialization information:

```
k = triple_des("DESCRYPTDESCRYPT", ECB, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
```

From the documentation, the params are as follows:

```
(key, [mode], [IV], [pad], [padmode])

key     -> Bytes containing the encryption key. 8 bytes for DES, 16 or 24 bytes
       for Triple DES
mode    -> Optional argument for encryption type, can be either
       pyDes.ECB (Electronic Code Book) or pyDes.CBC (Cypher Block Chaining)
IV      -> Optional Initial Value bytes, must be supplied if using CBC mode.
       Length must be 8 bytes.
pad     -> Optional argument, set the pad character (PAD_NORMAL) to use during
       all encrypt/decrpt operations done with this instance.
padmode -> Optional argument, set the padding mode (PAD_NORMAL or PAD_PKCS5)
       to use during all encrypt/decrpt operations done with this instance.
```

So, in my modified example, I've configured the params like this...

```
Key: DESCRYPTDESCRYPT
Mode: ECB
IV: "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
pad: None
padmode: PAD_PKCS5
```

So, from here, you'll need to change the 'data' variable above to the ciphertext you want to decrypt and then load your wordlist into an array, set up a loop to iterate the values in the array through the 'key' param...

Comment: Line 8 in your error message - `ValueError("Invalid triple DES key size. Key must be either 16 or 24 bytes long")`.  You need a 16 or 24 byte key length.  Remember, 1 character = 1 byte.

Comment: hmmm.. can you please provide a working example, for my question? :P